# Openlayers timezone symbolizer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have my openlayers-based website, and we are planning to add a timezone map. We want to show a clock with the current time on top of each area. Is that even possible with Openlayers and Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenLayers 3 Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/) page is always a good start.

Here you can find a very good [kml-timezones](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml-timezones.html) example. This is the essential part to create your timezone-layer:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/examples/data/kml/timezones.kml',
    format: new ol.format.KML({
      extractStyles: false
    })
  }),
  style: styleFunction
});
```

Instead of using the `displayFeatureInfo`  function of that example you want to display labels for the features at the top of the map.

The [vector-labels](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html) example helps you to understand how to create text labels. Adjust the `createTextStyle` function how you want your text to look like:

```
var createTextStyle = function(feature, resolution, dom) {
  var align = dom.align.value;
  var baseline = dom.baseline.value; // use 'bottom' to display your label at the top!
  var size = dom.size.value;
  var offsetX = parseInt(dom.offsetX.value, 10);
  var offsetY = parseInt(dom.offsetY.value, 10);
  var weight = dom.weight.value;
  var rotation = parseFloat(dom.rotation.value);
  var font = weight + ' ' + size + ' ' + dom.font.value;
  var fillColor = dom.color.value;
  var outlineColor = dom.outline.value;
  var outlineWidth = parseInt(dom.outlineWidth.value, 10);

  return new ol.style.Text({
    textAlign: align,
    textBaseline: baseline,
    font: font,
    text: getText(feature, resolution, dom),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: fillColor}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: outlineColor, width: outlineWidth}),
    offsetX: offsetX,
    offsetY: offsetY,
    rotation: rotation
  });
};
```

To display the labels at the top of your map you have to set the baseline to bottom.